# Using Python to Collect Historical 30yr Treasury Bond Prices

Tags: python, post, input, web

I am using the website https://www.treasurydirect.gov/GA-FI/FedInvest/selectSecurityPriceDate.htm.

This website gives me access to historical bond prices based on the CUSIP number of the bond. I am trying to construct a chart to display the historical prices of a specific bond over time, however the website does not support this function. Instead it allows the user to look up specific dates.

I am curious if there is a way in Python to input the dates I want to lookup and then "post" these dates to the website and read the resulting webpage to search for my specific CUSIP and construct a dict of dates and prices in order to graphically visualize and interpret this data.

This would be an easy task if inputting a date took you to a specific directory of the website that could be manipulated in the address, but unfortunately the way the site is setup it seems to be a built in program that displays the corresponding charts for each day. If anyone could help me out with this I would greatly appreciate it!

I have tried using urllib2 and the Request function to send a dict with the parameters for priceData.day, month, and year, but it does not open the correct webpage.

```
import urllib2
def URLRequest(url, params, method="GET"):
    if method == "POST":
        return urllib2.Request(url, data=urllib.urlencode(params))
    else:
        return urllib2.Request(url + "?" + urllib.urlencode(params))
data = URLRequest("https://www.treasurydirect.gov/GA-FI/FedInvest/selectSecurityPriceDate.htm",{"priceData.month":"7","priceData.day":"8","priceData.year":"2013"}, method="POST")
response = urllib2.urlopen(data)
response.read()
[Out]: The source file of the website without displaying the information I need
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: I just did, please don't down vote me for that...

Comment: I don't see any code in your post. I don't see error messages, I don't see your output, or input.

Comment: I explained in words and now I have included my code

Comment: Real browser send also `submit=Show+Prices`, **cookies** and **user-agent**. Maybe server check cookies and/or user-agent and send different results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Page required `submit=Show+Prices` in POST data.

I tested it with `curl` on linux.

Without `submit=Show+Prices` this give me normal page:

```
curl -k https://www.treasurydirect.gov/GA-FI/FedInvest/selectSecurityPriceDate.htm -d "priceDate.month=7&priceDate.day=8&priceDate.year=2013"
```

With `submit=Show+Prices` this give me page with data:

```
curl -k https://www.treasurydirect.gov/GA-FI/FedInvest/selectSecurityPriceDate.htm -d "priceDate.month=7&priceDate.day=8&priceDate.year=2013&submit=Show+Prices"
```

Comment: You are awesome. Thanks a ton, I'll post my code once it's finished.

Comment: I posted another question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17550235/website-caching-info-using-urllib2-in-python

Could you help me with this? It seems to be related

Comment: You are welcome. I make (sometimes) webscraping with urllib and [pyquery](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery). And I use curl and firebug (in Firefox) to help.